# why does java Charset need extra import?

Tags: java, io

I am teaching myself a little about Files and I/O in Java, based on this tutorial: [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#creating)

Now, after writing some examples to understand input and output, I got a question regarding the import of certain libraries.

I created the following example program, and I ask myself why the program says:

> Cannot find symbol - class Charset

```
import java.nio.*;

public class test
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
}

}
```

I know that the solution is to import the following
    import java.nio.charset.*;

But why do I have to import it, if I already got the parent library?

Comment: What "parent library"? Note that when you import `java.nio` (which you didn't), you *only* import that package, not any sub-packages.

Comment: sorry, it was java.nio.*;

Comment: `java.nio.charset` is a different package from `java.nio`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You import packages, not libraries.  A library might contain multiple packages, but that doesn't mean that you can get away from importing them individually.

Also, the Charset class belongs to the java.nio.**charset** package, while you've imported the java.nio.**file** package.  There is no relation between the two - one isn't a parent of the other.

Answer (score 0):

> But why do I have to import it, if I already got the parent library?

No you are not, imagine packages as folders and sub folder defining a path...

When you import this

java.nio.file.*;

You are accessing all classes in that "path"

But Charset is in the  java.nio.charset folder....wich is actually another totally different path...

You mean importing all from a parent package like

> java.nio.*;

Answer (score 0):

An example to help is when you think about it the object package is the king of all the packages, yet if you import it you don't get everything under it.  Then there would be no need to ever import stuff, not to mention the problems this creates.  You can't  just import a package and expect everything created under it to come with it.  Sub packages are still needed for storage reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**import java.nio.charset.Charset;**